# PHP - Page Building and Formatting with PHP

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to build an informational page on my website that is fairly expansive, enough so that it has it's own Nav and Sub-nav.

The nav is currently built and now I need to introduce and link the content to appear the way that I want it to, but that's where I'm beginning to get lost in how I should structure it efficiently. I'll try to give as detailed a run-down of the structure it lives is as possible.

First of all, all of this must happen on one page of the site. The links in the navigation should trigger different content, but in interacting with this Nav one should never leave the page (I suppose reloading it is okay, but not preferable).

The page is loaded from a "template.php" that basically just has different div's that contain a function $definepage to load their content.

Something like:

```
<div class="middleArea" id="infoPage">
   <div id="Nav" class="content">
      <?php require($definepage); ?>
   </div>

   <div class="returnNav"><img>backbutton</img></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a separate div in this template that will be for showing the user's desired content dynamically without leaving the page. So if "Item 6a" is chosen this div will be loaded with the item's corresponding content, then if "Item2b" is chosen the div instead is loaded with that item's content - with the previous content no longer there.

I have about eight Main Nav items and six of them have multi-item subnavs. So there's a lot of content which is why I didn't want to have it all existing on the page and simply hidden and shown with the links for page load reasons.

But I need the links from the first div (in the template) to load the correct .php in the (to be) content area div, as well as stay "active" while the corresponding php is loaded to remain highlighted - show that that link's info is currently being shown.

Can this be accomplished through *a href="#anchors"*? Or can I somehow have the content area exist in the same div of the template, but still load from external php so all of it doesn't have to load with the page? (I figured php within php within php was a bad idea)

Comment: Note that if it's an informational page, and you want maximum SEO, do not use AJAX. Google supports it somewhat, but your SEO score will still suffer if you don't do it exactly the way google likes it (which changes over time). AJAX should really only be reserved for use by dynamic stuff, like visit counters, or live twitter feeds...etc. If you just want a site that looks good, without caring about SEO (this is stilll feasible, but just not recommended), go ahead and make as dynamic as you want. Just understand that your search ranking will suffer as a result.

Comment: @Populus What would you recommend in place of AJAX? SEO is a concern of mine, so if there is a better way to preserve performance and ratings on SEO I'd prefer it.

Comment: If you want dynamic page without reloading page, there is nothing you can do except ajax. The best way for SEO is to have individual pages, or at least pages that appear to be indivudual

Comment: @Populus What about the "meet-in-the-middle" approach I bring up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32149474/5149745)? Ideally only the content of the iframe should be re-loading, but will still consist of separate, searchable pages. Do you think this will function alright?

Comment: sorry, I stopped reading at "iframe" :P It may be an outdated thinking, but iframes have been notorious for being insecure and a playpen for hackers. Also regarding SEO, iframes aren't normally crawled by google, so it'd be no different from AJAX in this respect.

Lastly, what is your justification for *requiring* a single page app? If it's not a requirement, start simple first. You can always enhance later (provided that your code is organized well enough)

Comment: @Populus well the project is a redesign of an existing page. The 'requirement' for a single page is actually a little softer than it sounds. The real intention there is to leave a collapsing/expanding Nav up all the time so the user can quickly navigate around its different sections to find what thing(s) they are looking for.



I've moved forward with the iframe structure, though I have some reservations after your comments on it. I've got it to function with search because the pages do have their own URLs, but I'm unsure how external searches will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Solution:

What if I use iframe to load a "separate site" as a separate directory in my site's root folder whose pages would contain the needed content. The links in the Nav would then be URLs pointing to the corresponding page in the "content site"?

Any glaring functionality issues here? On paper it looks like it would work.

*(*Please disregard the previous idiom's ironic use for the web medium)*

Comment: The nav's links to iframe content is fine, and search engines will crawl your content through those links. However, you'd still need to have to populate meta data for each individual "page" for SEO (e.g. keywords, description, title).

Comment: @Populus This has broken into two comment chains now haha. I've gotten the internal search function to target the iframe, but I'm not sure how to handle coming up with the URLs from external (like a native google search) since they were meant to be loaded in an iframe and not in a browser window itself. I'd need some way to redirect to the page, and fill the iframe with the result URL whenever it's clicked as a direct link. Which seems to crumble this structure a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load some content without reloading the page, you may use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript to change the content of the page without reloading it/changing the URL, using AJAX calls as mentioned by @antoyo to transfer data between the server and client as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for an ajax request with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/dj50uev5/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder">

</div>

<input type="button" value="Ajax Call Test" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "internalUrlOrFile.txt",
        context: document.body
    }).success(function(data) {
        $('#placeholder').html( data );
    });
});
```

I can't really provide a working sample where the content is added automatically due to cross domain origin policies.

Let me know if you need further clarification.